# ImageMagick Animated GIF not working correctly

Tags: imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

I am trying to upload some animated GIFs. Some work great, others get messed up as seen in the attached example. Here is my basic ImageMagick command:

`exec(" convert elephant_upload.gif -strip -resize 600x600 elephant_output.gif ");`

Anyone know what im doing wrong here?

Original Gif:

[image]

Processed Gif:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to coalesce your frames in Imagemagick before resizing in your command. So try

```
convert elephant.gif -strip -coalesce -resize 600x600 -layers optimize x.gif
```

[image]